# Char or String -> Unicode value in Scala?

Tags: scala, unicode

So I'm working through a few of the exercises in "Scala for the Impatient" and one of them is:

Write a `for` loop for computing the product of the Unicode codes of all letters in a string. For example, the product of the characters in "Hello" is 9415087488 L.

The next problem is to do the same, but without a `for` loop - it hints that we should check `StringOps` in Scaladoc.

I checked the `RichChar` and `StringOps` section in Scaladoc, and perhaps I'm misreading or looking in the wrong places, but I can't find anything that gets me to match their output. I've thus far tried:

```
scala> x.foldLeft(1)(_ * _.toInt)
res0: Int = 825152896

scala> x.foldLeft(1)(_ * _.getNumericValue)
res5: Int = 2518992

scala> x.foldLeft(1)(_ * _.intValue())
res6: Int = 825152896

scala> var x = 1
x: Int = 1

scala> for (c <- "Hello") x *= c.toInt

scala> x
res12: Int = 825152896
```

Which does not match their output.

How do I do this, in both the `for` and non-`for` way?

Thanks!

Comment: There's another way, if you do it in two steps. Hint: the last of the two methods only have an implicit parameter.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you do `x.foldLeft(1)(_ * _.toInt)`, the result type will be inference to an `Int`, but 9415087488 is too large for an `Int` to store it.

So you need to tell Scala using `Long` to store it.

```
scala> val x = "Hello"
x: java.lang.String = Hello

scala> x.foldLeft(1L)(_ * _.toInt)
res1: Long = 9415087488

scala> var x: Long = 1
x: Long = 1

scala> for (c <- "Hello") x *= c.toInt

scala> x
res7: Long = 9415087488
```

Comment: Thanks from me too. Oddly, in the pdf-Version I just downloaded, the wrong value is given (825152896).

Comment: strange, but with "for (fi <- "Hello")  i *= fi.toChar" I have same value as in book. Hmmm.

Comment: @Dubysa whats the type of `i` variable? Your `i` need to be an `Long` to get correct result, or Scala will inference the expression to be an `Int` (an Int multiple with a Char will become an Int) which will cause overflow.

Comment: well, my REPL does not see a problem in there (always knew my laptop is smart :D) I did post it as an answer.

Comment: You can also write it as (x :\ 1L)(_ * _)

Answer (score 13):

If you convert each RichChar of String .toLong it's also works. For example, this:

`str.map (_.toLong).product` - work's fine and without foldLeft or cycles

This is cyclic variant:

```
def product(str: String): Long = {
    var prod: Long = 1
    for (ch <- str) prod *= ch
    prod
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There's a special "product" method in StringOps which multiplies up the elements of the collection. But it uses Char type because the string consist of char elements. And we're having overflow while trying to compute "Hello".product. So I converted the string to Vector of Long Unicode values by "Hello".map(_.toLong) and computed the product of its elements by this code:

```
scala> "Hello".map(_.toLong).product
res79: Long = 9415087488
```

Comment: Thanks! I suspected an overflow, too. But was unsure how to ask it to map it to a Long.

Comment: The for loop in Rihad's answer and the map in this answer are notational variants.  The compiler converts the for loop to a map, I believe. It's a matter of taste which you use.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way:

```
scala> (for (c <- "Hello") yield c.toLong).product
res36: Long = 9415087488
```

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way I've found to do this is:

```
"Hello".foldLeft(1L)((x:Long, y:Char) => x*y)
```

The method takes two parameters: a Long and a delegate function that takes a Long and a Char and returns a Long.  You can pass an anonymous function in directly like this, or you can define the function elsewhere and pass it in, like so:

```
def multiply(x:Long, y:Char) = {
    x*y
}
"Hello".foldLeft(1L)(multiply)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd think the conversion to intermediate map is inefficient because in this case the collection is iterated twice: once to create map of longs and second time to multiply all elements. Unnecessary temporary collection of Long's also is not needed. I give my vote to

```
"Hello".foldLeft(1L)(_ * _)
```

Answer (score 1):

The exercise required to don't use for loop, so I've gone recursive:

```
def unicode_rec(s: String): Int = 
  if(s == "") 1 
  else s.head.toInt * unicode_rec(s.tail)
```

Comment: Recursive function was also my first intuition for a solution. You can actually leave out the `.toInt` part of `s.head.toInt` since `.head`returns a _Char_. Also, to get the non-overflow result from the newer edition of the book (9415087488L), return type of the function should be _Long_ or _BigInt_ :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another variant:

```
"Hello".aggregate(1L)({(prod,ch) => prod * ch.toLong}, {(p1,p2)=>p1*p2})
```

Answer (score 0):

So here we have in bunch together :)

```
    // one way
    val longs = for (c <- str) yield c.toLong
    println(longs.product)

    // 2nd way
    println(str.foldLeft(1L)(_ * _.toInt))

    // 3rd way
    var x = 1L
    for (c <- str) yield x *= c.toInt
    println(x)

    // 4th way
    var product = 1L
    for (c <- str) {
      product *= c.toInt
    }
    println(product)

    // 5th way
    println(str.map(_.toLong).product)

    // 6th way
    println(str.foldLeft(1L)(_ * _))

    // 7th way
    println(str.map(_.toLong).reduceLeft(_ * _)) // my IDE warns `Replace reduce with product` 

    // 8th way
    println(str.map(_.toLong).scanLeft(1L)(_ * _).last)

    // 9th way
    println(str.map(_.toLong).reduce((x, y) => (x * y))) // my IDE warns `Replace reduce with product`

   // using recursion
   def exercise9(str: String): Long = {
    var product = str.head.toLong
    if (str.tail.length > 0) {
        product *= exercise9(str.tail)
    }
    product
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also progressing wit the same book.
Might look like a bit java-ish flavoured, but it does its job:

```
scala> "Hello".map( x => x.toLong).reduce( (a, b) => a * b)
val res45: Long = 9415087488
```

Comment: 1st - This solution was posted a year ago. 2nd - `825152896` is the wrong result. Re-read the question and all the other answers from 8 years ago.

Comment: 1st - not the same solution. 2nd: 825152896 was the product from the book itself :). CHanged to use long / unicode.

Comment: Re-1st: Sure it is. See "9th way" posted by R Sun.