# Get the Unicode when an emoji is provided as input using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, unicode, emoji

I am a newbie to scala and spark. Im developing a big data project and i want to input an emoji and get its unicode using **scala** and **spark**. I tried finding resources to use as a guide but i am unable to find any.

eg -

```
val inputEmoji =
```

then output should provide **U+1F603** as the answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Char or String -> Unicode value in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165635/char-or-string-unicode-value-in-scala)

Comment: No this question requirement is different from mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encode the emoji in UTF-32 in Spark:

```
val inputEmoji = ""

val df = Seq(inputEmoji).toDF("emoji")

val result = df.selectExpr(
    "emoji",
    "'U+' || trim('0', string(hex(encode(emoji, 'utf-32')))) as result"
)

result.show
+-----+-------+
|emoji| result|
+-----+-------+
|   |U+1F603|
+-----+-------+
```